# Why QT's QList methods are made compatible with std::list

Tags: c++, qt, compatibility, std

What is the reason for having methods such as `void QList::push_back ( const T & value )`

in QT when it is doing the same thing as `append()` What kind of compatibly does the documentation means. Can any one please elaborate this

Following is the statement from official [documentation](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qlist.html) of QT

"***This function is provided for STL compatibility. It is equivalent to append(value)***"

Comment: @Nbr44 Please post this as an answer so it will be a help to all :) and thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is typically used so that method templates that expect standard containers as their template parameters can be used with a `QList` as well, since they will share the same methods.

For example:

```
template<typename Container>
void move_elements(Container &to, const std::vector<int> &from)
{
  for (auto elem : from)
    to.push_back(elem);
}
```

Could be called with both a `std::list<int>` and a `QList<int>` as the `to` parameter.

Comment: +1. Even better, it also allows interoperability with the standard library, such as `std::back_inserter`.

Comment: if you are able to use `C++11`, avoid copying multiple times. Use `for (const auto& elem : from) to.emplace_back(elem);` instead.

Comment: @walle I don't think it really matters with `int`s.

Comment: ok, i agree for `int`, but i think most people would do the same with structs, objects and so on

Answer (score 4):

it is for compatibility, so you can send QList to 
**algorithms**
operating on standard containers. I think this is main benefit, so you can use all operations from `<algorithm>`. I give an example of `find_if` from `<algorithm>`:

```
bool hasChildChecked(){
      return std::find_if(childItems_.begin(), 
                          childItems_.end(),checked()) != childItems_.end();
      }
```

where my childItems_ is declared as:

```
QList<TreeItem*> childItems_;

struct checked {
           bool operator()(const TreeItem* t) {
               return t->moduleInfo_.currentlyEnabled;
           }
       };
```

this kind of compatibility really saves my time and makes coding much easier.

Answer (score 1):

You may run into this case:

```
template <
    template <
        typename ValueType,
        typename Allocator
    > class Container
> class garbage_collector
{
    /* some implementation */
};
```

Because QList has the same method names as the STL container, it could be used in this context.

Answer (score 0):

STL (Standard Template Library) of C++ uses the function push_back() for lists and vectors and thus it is a familiar method for most of the C++ programmers. Thus, they have provided an extra method for template parameter compatibility while calling the method.